# Iframe do facebook com com altura maior no Firefox

Tags: html, css, facebook, iframe, plugin

Defini a altura para 230px, mas no Firefox fica maior que no Chrome, IE e Edge

Isso acaba interferindo na margem do iframe com o elemento abaixo, que fica menor no Firefox

Sabem me dizer como padronizar o iframe para todos os navegadores?

Link do plugin: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin

```html
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Ffacebook&tabs&width=280&height=230&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId" width="280" height="230" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: Essa rolagem é do conteúdo que está dentro do iframe. Você não tem permissão para modificar nada. Se não tiver uma opção de configuração, não tem jeito.

Comment: Muitos sites usam sem essa barra. E esqueci de mencionar que no Chrome ela não aparece

Comment: Verifica então na documentação se há algum parâmetro que faça isso. Mas eu reparei agora, você esta limitando a altura do iframe, então, o que você espera que aconteça com o conteúdo, já que ele é maior?

Comment: Não é isso também, já modifiquei pra várias alturas e não resolve, só quebra o iframe

Comment: Resolvi esse problema, editei com o novo problema